# Android: Applying StateListDrawable to LinearLayout programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a `StateListDrawable` instance

```
StateListDrawable stateListDrawable = new StateListDrawable();

stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_enabled}, new ColorDrawable(Color.RED));
stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_pressed}, new ColorDrawable(Color.GREEN));
stateListDrawable.addState(new int[]{ android.R.attr.state_focused}, new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
```

I am trying to attach it to a LinearLayout object as follow

```
myLinearLayout.setBackground(StateListDrawable);
```

But, the active_state color is being set as specified in the stateListDrawable. The entire linear layout's background appreas RED but when I press it, it remains the same.

My question is, is it possible to set the background of the linear layout using StateListDrawable?

Comment: Order is of importance here. When you press the the LL, the states are check in the order specified => `enabled` => `pressed` => `focused`. `enabled` is found to be true and the color is set to `RED`. To see what I am saying, add `android.R.attr.state_pressed` first, add `android.R.attr.state_focused` second, and finally `android.R.attr.state_enabled`.

Comment: It worked :) Post it as an answer